# Comparing two nested arrays of objects, and exclude the elements who match values by "id" into new array in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

#### I have two arrays of objects, i need to match arr2 names to arr1 by matching id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `Map` from `arr2`, keyed by `id` and with as value the corresponding object.

Then map `arr1`, looking up the object in the Map, both for the object itself and the children:

```js
let arr1 = [{id:1,children:[9]},{id:2,children:[]},{id:14,children:[3,42]},];
let arr2 = [{id:1,name:"name1"},{id:2,name:"name2"},{id:3,name:"name3"},{id:9,name:"name9"},{id:14,name:"name14"},{id:42,name:"name42"},{id:100,name:"idNotMatch"}];

const map = new Map(arr2.map(o => [o.id, o]));
const result = arr1.map(o => 
    Object.assign(o, {
        ...map.get(o.id),
        children: o.children.map(id => map.get(id))
    })
);

console.log(result);
```